# Выводить элементы массива по свойству объекта из другого объекта во vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Прошу помочь. Необходимо отрисовать картинку в том случае, если `SECTION_ID`, будет равен `ID` отрисованного `NAME` из другого массива.
Если можно с примером кода.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он задан картинками и не содержит внятного текстового описания - другие участники (с той же задачей/проблемой) не смогут его найти через поиск.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Директива [v-if](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if) используется для рендеринга блока по условию.
Блок будет отображаться только в том случае, если выражение директивы возвращает значение, приводимое к **true**.

Чтобы проверить ваше выражение на истинность, вы можете воспользоваться [операторами сравнения](https://learn.javascript.ru/comparison)

```
... v-if="section.ID === element.SECTION_ID" ...
```

Или, в вашем случае, можно сразу отобрать только подходящие под условие данные из `elements`, допустим воспользовавшись выражением:

```
... v-for="element in elements.filter((x)=>x.SECTION_ID === section.ID)" ...
```

после чего можно убрать `v-if`, т.к. вы уже проверили условие в методе [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)